# Find a specific name in a column, bring in the value in the corresponding row, in the column I designate in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a worksheet that people will go into and put their name down to sign up for a meeting for a specific date. In a separate sheet, I have their names and I manually input the days they signed up for to make it easier to see who has, and who has not signed up for the year.

Can I use a formula in the separate sheet next to their name that says, "if this name is true anywhere in this column, bring in the value (date) on the corresponding row in the column I specify".

So for instance in Column A is for dates. Column E is for Managers' Names. If column E says "john doe" then bring in on another worksheet the value in Column A (same row), so 2/10/2015.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Index(Match should work for this

Comment: vlookup should also work for this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is on "Sheet1" and your formula in "Sheet2", I would use

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("john doe",Sheet1!E:E,0))
```

or more probably

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!E:E,0))
```

or even this (to be explicit)

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!E:E,0))
```